# Accessing MS Access database in different subnet using opendatasource SQL Server 2008

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, networking, ms-access-2007, linked-server

I want read data from MS Access on 192.168.1.203 from SQL Server 2008 on 192.168.100.202 using OPENDatasource.

I get this error:

> The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file '\192.168.1.203\Time Attendance System 4.3.1.25\sample\HITFPTA.mdb'.  It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data."

Please help me fix this, friend.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely an issue with folder permissions. In order to share a Jet database, all users must have read/write permissions on the folder where the .MDB file exists. That's because the first user to connect to the database creates a locking file (.LDB) and subsequent users must be able to write to that locking file. (When the last user disconnects, Access will try to delete the locking file, but it's actually not essential that users have Delete permission on the folder).

Comment: that's not any user connect or open this mdb database so doesn't create a locking file. and this sample folder was shared to everyone